# IIS Application + Javascript

Tags: javascript, iis-7

So in IIS 7 I created an app called "Test" under my regular website:

Here is how its setup

Site: www.site.com
App: www.site.com/Test

Now in the Test app I have a masterpage which has the following script tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Assets/Includes/Javascript/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
```

When I deployed the site and looked at Firebug its referencing:
http://www.site.com/assets/includes/javascript/jquery-1.4.2.min.js

I would like it to reference:
http://www.site.com/TEST/assets/includes/javascript/jquery-1.4.2.min.js

What am I doing wrong here? Is this a configuration in IIS7 or should I reference the file differently (I would prefer not to use absolute).

I have deployed applications in virtual directories before under IIS6 and I don't remember having this problem!

Thanking you in advance

Comment: You need to use a relative path as opposed to an absolute path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is ASP.net MVC try:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%=Url.Content("~/Assets/Includes/Javascript/jquery-1.4.2.min.js")%>"></script>
```

If this is just ASP.net try adding ~

Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Assets/Includes/Javascript/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Go with Gabe if you are using MVC. Otherwise, you will need to call Page.ResolveUrl to resolve the url because the ~ wont work in `<script>` tags.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/Assets/Includes/Javascript/jquery-1.4.2.min.js") %>'></script>
```